# Get order nodes with childrens in XML XPATH POSTGRES

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath

I have some XML in a table (let's call xml_table), I need get the parents with his children in perfect order but it doesn't happend. I'll simplify problem.

This is my XML:

```
<group name="A">
    <category target_id="1001">
        <category flow_id="0" />
        <category flow_id="1" />
        <category flow_id="2" />
    </category>
</group>

<group name="B">
    <category target_id="1002">
        <category flow_id="0" />
    </category>
    <category target_id="1003">
        <category flow_id="0" />
    </category>
    <category target_id="1004">
        <category flow_id="0" />
    </category>
    <category target_id="1005">
        <category flow_id="0" />
    </category>
</group>

<group name="C">
    <category target_id="1006">
        <category flow_id="0" />
        <category flow_id="2" />
        <category flow_id="4" />
    </category>
    <category target_id="1007">
        <category flow_id="1" />
        <category flow_id="6" />
    </category>
    <category target_id="1008">
        <category flow_id="0" />
        <category flow_id="1" />
        <category flow_id="2" />
    </category>
    <category target_id="1009">
        <category flow_id="0" />
        <category flow_id="1" />
        <category flow_id="2" />
        <category flow_id="3" />
    </category>
</group>
```

And this is my SQL:

```
SELECT      unnest((xpath('@name', team)::text[])) AS group
            ,unnest((xpath('category/@target_id', team)::text[]::int[]))  AS target_id
            ,unnest((xpath('category/category/@flow_id', team)::text[]::int[]))  AS flow_id
FROM (

        SELECT team::xml
        FROM xml_table;
    )
```

With this SQL i get perfect in case GROUP A and B. When in the group is only 1 target_id and many flow_id (like A)

| Group | Target_id | Flow_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1001 | 0 |
| A | 1001 | 1 |
| A | 1001 | 2 |

Works Perfect

When each target_id has only one flow_id, doesn't care if is a lot of target_id, like group B.

| Group | Target_id | Flow_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1002 | 0 |
| B | 1003 | 0 |
| B | 1004 | 0 |
| B | 1005 | 0 |

Works perfect too.

But in the group C doesn't work, repeat many times the instance target_id - flow_id and even mix it, for example appear target_id with other flow_id than doesn't belong (here repeat 3 times Target_id-Flow_id.

| Group | Target_id | Flow_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 1006 | 0 |
| C | 1006 | 2 |
| C | 1006 | 4 |
| C | 1006 | 0 |
| C | 1006 | 2 |
| C | 1006 | 4 |
| C | 1006 | 0 |
| C | 1006 | 2 |
| C | 1006 | 4 |

Mix too

| Group | Target_id | Flow_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 1006 | 0 |
| C | 1006 | 2 |
| **C** | **1006** | **6** |

Flow_id = 6 is part of target_id = 1007 and it appear in target_id = 1006.

This I want to get, the same structure of the XML holding the order.

| Group | Target_id | Flow_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1001 | 0 |
| A | 1001 | 1 |
| A | 1001 | 2 |
| B | 1002 | 0 |
| B | 1003 | 0 |
| B | 1004 | 0 |
| B | 1005 | 0 |
| C | 1006 | 0 |
| C | 1006 | 2 |
| C | 1006 | 4 |
| C | 1007 | 1 |
| C | 1007 | 6 |
| C | 1008 | 0 |
| C | 1008 | 1 |
| C | 1008 | 2 |
| C | 1009 | 0 |
| C | 1009 | 1 |
| C | 1009 | 2 |
| C | 1009 | 3 |

Comment: Xpaths are missing context I think, it should be `//category/@target_id`, `/group/@name` and `//category/category/@flow_id`

Answer (score 1):

XPATH expressions can get really nasty with complex tasks. My suggestion: Split the operations in multiple subqueries or CTEs to make things easier. This might give you some inspiration:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  g.group_id,
  t.target_id,
  unnest(xpath('//group[@name="'||g.group_id||'"]/category/category/@flow_id', team)::text[]) flow_id
FROM 
  xml_table x,
  LATERAL unnest(xpath('//group/@name', x.team)::text[]) g (group_id),
  LATERAL unnest(xpath('//group[@name="'||g.group_id||'"]/category/@target_id', team)::text[]) t (target_id)  
ORDER BY g.group_id,t.target_id,flow_id;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4d7b8a3c659f3984b9b76504ce41c405)

Comment: Thanks man for your answer, sorry for the late reply. I find other solution first, unnest by stages, not all together. Anyway your sql is another way than i don't know, thanks for that. But in the XML have 279 records and this sql return 450. I don't know why, i will look and check later. Anyway this give me another perspective, thanks!